# 2 sited hosted in NGINX with separate SSL certs. IE8 posting invalid when starting at one site going to the other

Tags: nginx, internet-explorer-8

If users with IE8 go directly to www.xyz.com, SSL cert is fine.  Users going directly to www.zyx.com have no issues with cert.  If users start at one site and go to the other, they get invalid cert with xyz being used on zyx which should not be happening.

Reading the forums NGINX has SNI enabled and I have the correct version of OpenSSL to be able to handle multiple certs.

IE8 seems to be the issue but these are customer facing sites.  Is there a fix to make NGINX work for the customers experiencing the issue.

Comment: I bet you that all those users with problems have Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

SNI requires both server AND client (web browser + OS) support. For OSes/web browsers not supporting SNI, such as Windows XP or IE6, the browser will be ignoring the SNI SSL header and still request the default SSL certificate of the server which will most probably mismatch with the actual domain you are visiting.

To be able to support almost all popular platforms I would suggest obtaining an different IP for each one of the domains you need to supply with SSL support and configure nginx to listen on a separate address for each one of these domains.